# Putting a pod to sleep in kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I know how to put a pod to sleep by command:

`kubectl -n logging patch sts <sts name> --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/command", "value": ["sleep", "infinity"] }]'`

Whats the command to wake up the pod?

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is to update the statefulset, changing the *command* parameter for its pods. The *command* parameter sets the entrypoint for the container, in other words, the command that is executed when starting the container.

You are setting that command to `sleep infinity`. Thus to wake up the pod, just update the statefulset and set the command to the original one.

The best solution to do this would be to just scale the statufulset to 0 replicas with:

```
kubectl -n logging scale sts <sts name> --replicas 0
```

And scale up to the original replicas number with:

```
kubectl -n logging scale sts <sts name> --replicas <original number>
```

This way you don't have any pod running `sleep infinity` in your cluster, and you will save costs by not having this useless pods wasting resources.

Comment: I dont want to put the pods on hold especially when my I want to get rid of data in mysql dir or remove data from the PV.

Comment: It was only a suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :-)